# convert chars from a position in a char array through an other position into a string in java

Tags: java, arrays, object-to-string

So i have a string and an array of characters and what i want to do is make a string with some characters between two positions  of this array.

Ex.
If
Arr = {a,b,c,d,e,f}
 I want 
Str= "bcde"

Comment: show us some efford please. what do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`String(char[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) constructor:

```
char[] arr = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

int start = 1, end = 4;

System.out.println(new String(arr, start, end - start + 1));
```

```
bcde
```